# Late static binding in d

Tags: d

I'm working on a generic collection class template, let's say `List(T)` where i'd like to be able to do something like php's late static binding. Might be best illustrated with some simplified sample code. This code compiles fine as is on dmd, but it needs a small change to be the way I want.

```
module main;

import std.stdio;
import std.string;

class List(T)
{
    private T[] _list;

    public void append(T t)
    {
        _list ~= t;
    }

    // this is where some help is needed...
    public List select(bool delegate(T t) dg)
    {
            // auto should be whatever subclass of List(T) is calling this method.
        auto result = new List!T();
        foreach(t; _list)
        {
            if (dg(t)) result.append(t);
        }
        return result;
    }

    int opApply(int delegate(ref T) dg)
    {
        int result = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < _list.length; i++)
        {
            result = dg(_list[i]);
            if (result)
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}

enum Gender
{
    MALE,
    FEMALE,
    SECRET
}

class Person
{
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;
    private string _email;
    private Gender _gender;

    @property public string firstName() {return _firstName;}
    @property public string lastName() {return _lastName;}
    @property public string email() {return _email;}
    @property public Gender gender() {return _gender;}


    public this()
    {
    }

    public this(string firstName, string lastName, Gender gender = Gender.SECRET, string email = "info@example.com")
    {
        this();

        this._firstName = firstName;
        this._lastName = lastName;
        this._gender = gender;
        this._email = email;
    }

    override public string toString()
    {
        if (email.length > 0)
        {
            return "%s %s <%s>".format(firstName, lastName, email);
        }
        else
        {
            return "%s %s".format(firstName, lastName);
        }
    }
}

class PeopleList : List!Person
{
    // I would like to be able to make this: public PeopleList selectByGender(Gender gender)
    public List!Person selectByGender(Gender gender)
    {
        return select(p => p.gender == gender);
    }
}

void main(string[] args)
{
    auto people = new PeopleList();
    people.append(new Person("Kris", "Herlaar", Gender.MALE));
    people.append(new Person("John", "Doe", Gender.MALE));
    people.append(new Person("Steve", "Wozniak", Gender.MALE));
    people.append(new Person("Walter", "Bright", Gender.MALE));
    people.append(new Person("Amelia", "Earhart", Gender.FEMALE, null));
    people.append(new Person("Susan", "Anthony", Gender.FEMALE, null));

    foreach(p; people.selectByGender(Gender.FEMALE))
    {
        writeln(p);
    }
}
```

How would I go about making sure that `PeopleList.select` would also return an instance of `PeopleList` instead of a `List!Person` so that the commented out declaration of `selectByGender` is correct?

I could probably mock about with `Object.factory(this.classinfo.name)` inside the implementation and actually get the correct type of instance for `result` but I figure that would not help with the declared return-type.

I'd want to make chaining methods possible so I'd need the compiler to allow me to return instances of whatever subclass is calling `List(T).select` I imagine it could be done with a nested template, but haven't been able to come up with anything that would compile, let alone seem elegant.

**Additional info in reply to received feedback**

I am aware of `std.algorithm` and of `filter`, In real life; this code does not represent an actual use-case but a thought experiment to learn more of the abilities/limits of D and its' templates.

Comment: aka you want something akin to java's clone; create a  new instance with the current (runtime) type

Comment: I know it's technically not "late" static binding, but It's not object cloning I'm after. I just want to return a subclass type from a superclass method, where the superclass doesn't really know about the subtype.

Comment: Maybe you should just go for the C++ STL approach and force composition instead of inheritance for your containers. This would solve your problem. Or do you have a good reason for needing inheritable containers?

Comment: I found a topic on d forums that might help you: [Find out most derived class in base class](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/learn/Find_out_most_derived_class_in_base_class_22892.html)

Comment: @RedX: because I want it to be as little code as possible. less code is less (opportunity for) bugs. Also, I need to be able to chain methods. Might be possible using c++ STL style composition, but I never liked c++ and so have no clue how they did it there ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Template This Parameters` as described in http://dlang.org/template.html#TemplateThisParameter

Here's some example code from the page.

```
interface Addable(T) {
    final R add(this R)(T t) {
        return cast(R)this; // cast is necessary, but safe
    }
}

class List(T) : Addable!T {
    List remove(T t) {
        return this;
    }
}

void main() {
    auto list = new List!int;
    list.add(1).remove(1); // ok
}
```

And here's your code using it.

```
module main;

import std.stdio;
import std.string;

class List(T)
{
    private T[] _list;

    public void append(T t)
    {
        _list ~= t;
    }

    // select is now templatized based on the most derived class
    public This select(this This)(bool delegate(T t) dg)
    {
        // auto should be whatever subclass of List(T) is calling this method.
        auto result = new This();
        foreach(t; _list)
        {
            if (dg(t)) result.append(t);
        }
        return result;
    }

    int opApply(int delegate(ref T) dg)
    {
        int result = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < _list.length; i++)
        {
            result = dg(_list[i]);
            if (result)
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}

enum Gender
{
    MALE,
    FEMALE,
    SECRET
}

class Person
{
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;
    private string _email;
    private Gender _gender;

    @property public string firstName() {return _firstName;}
    @property public string lastName() {return _lastName;}
    @property public string email() {return _email;}
    @property public Gender gender() {return _gender;}


    public this()
    {
    }

    public this(string firstName, string lastName, Gender gender = Gender.SECRET, string email = "info@example.com")
    {
        this();

        this._firstName = firstName;
        this._lastName = lastName;
        this._gender = gender;
        this._email = email;
    }

    override public string toString()
    {
        if (email.length > 0)
        {
            return "%s %s <%s>".format(firstName, lastName, email);
        }
        else
        {
            return "%s %s".format(firstName, lastName);
        }
    }
}

class PeopleList : List!Person
{
    public PeopleList selectByGender(Gender gender)
    {
        return this.select(p => p.gender == gender);
    }
}

void main(string[] args)
{
    auto people = new PeopleList();
    people.append(new Person("Kris", "Herlaar", Gender.MALE));
    people.append(new Person("John", "Doe", Gender.MALE));
    people.append(new Person("Steve", "Wozniak", Gender.MALE));
    people.append(new Person("Walter", "Bright", Gender.MALE));
    people.append(new Person("Amelia", "Earhart", Gender.FEMALE, null));
    people.append(new Person("Susan", "Anthony", Gender.FEMALE, null));

    foreach(p; people.selectByGender(Gender.FEMALE))
    {
        writeln(p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an unfortunate use of inheritance. `PersonList` shouldn't exist: It is not in any way polymorhpic.

What I think you intend to do is to provide a helper method: selecting people by gender from a list.
D has something called unified function call syntax, which allows you to call free functions as if the first parameter was the actual `this` instance. So you could rewrite your code like this:

```
public List!People selectByGender(List!People list, Gender gender)
{
    return list.select(p => p.gender == gender);
}

void main(string[] args)
{
    auto people = new List!People();

    // ...

    foreach(p; people.selectByGender(Gender.FEMALE))
    {
        writeln(p);
    }
}
```

I don't know if you've looked into std.algorithm yet. But it basically renders all your `List(T)` code redundant. You could just create an array (or any other `range` of `Person`) with your persons and then do:

```
foreach (p; people.filter!(p => p.gender == Gender.FEMALE))
{
    writeln(p);
}
```

and be done with it. This style resembles (essential elements of) functional programming, pipes and filters or component programming (within the D community), whatever you like to call it. Also `filter` et al won't allocate a new List, but rather generate their results from the original array on the fly, or lazily, or streaming. You can force them to save the results in a new buffer by using `array` from std.array.

This is one of the basic cases where forcing yourself to think in Inheritance hierachies is not the most elegant way to go.

Comment: I'm trying to find limits to what is possible with d, not do anything in particular. Just teaching myself here.