# Get the calling object or method in d

Tags: d

Somewhat related to [my previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197531/late-static-binding-in-d)

Is there a way to get the calling Object from within a function or method in d?

example:

```
class Foo
{
    public void bar()
    {
        auto ci = whoCalledMe();
        // ci should be something that points me to baz.qux, _if_ baz.qux made the call

    }
}

class Baz
{
    void qux()
    {
        auto foo = new Foo();
        foo.bar();
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. Does something like `whoCalledMe` exist? and if so, what is it called?
2. if something does exist, can it be used at compile time (in a template) and if so, how?

Alternatively;

1. is it possible to get access to the call stack at runtime? like with php's `debug_backtrace`?

Comment: kinda hard when the call can also be made from `main`

Comment: @ratchetfreak: I am missing the point of your comment? remember the code is there to explain a general thing, not to constrain the question.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to achieve what you want in any compiled language. Regarding question 2: at compile time there can be multiple callers of a function, you could get list of all possible callers (and I don't think that is possible in D now).

Comment: @MichalMinich: As long as the function I'm calling is a template I can compile a specialized version of the function at compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not directly possible to get information about your "caller". You might have some luck getting the address from the call stack, but this is a low-level operation and depends on things such as whether your program was compiled with stack frames. After you have the address, you could in theory convert it to a function name and line number, provided debugging symbols are available for your program's binary, but (again) this is highly platform-specific and depends on the toolchain used to compile your program.

As an alternative, you might find this helpful:

```
void callee(string file=__FILE__, int line=__LINE__, string func=__FUNCTION__)()
{
    writefln("I was called by %s, which is in %s at line %d!", func, file, line);
}

void caller()
{
    // Thanks to IFTI, we can call the function as usual.
    callee();
}
```

But note that you can't use this trick for non-final class methods, because every call to the function will generate a new template instance (and the compiler needs to know the address of all virtual methods of a class beforehand).

Comment: i'd found, and even used, __FILE__ and __LINE__ before but didn't know about __FUNCTION__ yet. are there more of these "magic constants"?

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` was [added](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/dmd/pull/1462) recently. The list for this family of keywords is [here](http://dlang.org/traits.html#specialkeywords).

Comment: hm this adds a lot of code bloat if you use it many times... its a not that ideal solution

Comment: To avoid "code bloat", make the template a stub that simply passes the compile-time variables to a non-template function as run-time variables. With `-inline`, it will be as if the second function was called directly with the file and line specified at the call site.

Comment: In general, `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, and `__FUNCTION__` should only be used as function arguments, not template arguments. Otherwise, you end up instantiating the function again every time you call it. And usually, it works just fine to add them as default arguments to the end of a function's signature. Advising anyone to use them as template arguments is almost always bad advice. Also, when you use them as function arguments, you don't _need_ a template, and it'll work with virtual functions.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on what [CyberShadow said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18211701/279684), since you can get the fully qualified name of the function by using `__FUNCTION__`, you can also get the function as a symbol using a mixin:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.typetuple;

void callee(string file=__FILE__, int line=__LINE__, string func=__FUNCTION__)()
{
    alias callerFunc = TypeTuple!(mixin(func))[0];
    static assert(&caller == &callerFunc);

    callerFunc();  // will eventually overflow the stack
}

void caller()
{
    callee();
}

void main()
{
    caller();
}
```

The stack will overflow here since these two functions end up calling each other recursively indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

Finding the caller is something debuggers do and generally requires having built the program with symbolic debug information switches turned on. Reading the debug info to figure this out is highly system dependent and is pretty advanced.

The exception unwinding mechanism also finds the caller, but those tables are not generated for functions that don't need them, and the tables do not include the name of the function.

Comment: How about if I were to request a feature `__CLASS__` like there are already `__FILE__`, `__LINE___` and `__FUNCTION__`? While we're at it I should probably also ask for `__MODULE__`. I'm more than willing to "do the required paperwork" by the way.

Comment: `__MODULE__` is already implemented. You can extract the class from `__FUNCTION__`, since it is fully-qualified.

Comment: @CyberShadow I could, but why require the clutter? It seems to fit too well with the other magic constants to not be there to me. So well actually that its absence could be seen as somewhat surprising. Must've read over `__MODULE__` since it's not in the code sample. My bad.

Comment: Every language addition must carry its weight. Besides, how do you expect it to work with nested classes?